# npm gives a TypeError every time I run it

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install a package using npm but no matter what I type in the console it just gives me errors.

I have version 16.6.2 of Node.js installed through the executable file from the website. I have tried reinstalling and repairing using the executable but it hasn't changed anything. I have also restarted my computer after reinstalling. It doesn't matter if I include any arguments after npm. Just typing npm and hitting enter will send these errors.

Node still runs just fine and will run the code I tell it to. It just seems to be npm that is broken.

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\agent.js:114:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:161:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\agent.js:114:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\index.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\agent.js:161:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

Comment: What are you trying you run using npm? Can you show your package.json (if there is one) and the code that's being run, because of which you're seeing this error?

Comment: I am just trying to run npm in the console and it won't work. Before I updated node I was able to install discord.js 13.1.0 just fine.
```{
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: So you're trying to run `npm install discord`?

Comment: Please make it clear, you are trying to install discord as @maazadeeb asked? or you are directedly trying to add something?

Comment: I'm just trying to run npm. I can enter `npm install discord` into the console or just `npm` it gives me the same error every time. 
I had a previous version of npm before I upgraded it and I was able to install things just fine through the console. Ever since I upgraded npm through the node.js installer, it has been giving me that error.

Comment: This is because you have updated your node, pls update any stable version. Use nvm to manage your node version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have it figured out. Something must have gotten corrupted during the installation. I downloaded a new installation executable. I removed nodejs and then I deleted the folder from my program files and reinstalled.  That fixed it. I should have tried this earlier but I didn't think about how there still might be files behind.

If you have this problem, uninstall using the installation file then go to your program files and delete the nodejs folder and then reinstall.

Comment: Yes, you are right, just delete node_module folder then install node and do npm install. Cool :)

Comment: I ran into this and had installed nodejs separately before installing nvm. I uninstalled both, then ran only nvm-setup.exe under Windows. After that, I used an admin cmd prompt to run the 'nvm install lts' command followed by 'nvm use <ver#>', which in my case was 'nvm use 16.14.0'. After that, npx worked. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 2):

I just installed the last LTS version of Node.JS (16.13.1, npm 8.1.2) and got the same problem. And I figured out too in my own way by running this in cmd:

```
CD /D "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules"
RMDIR /S /Q "%CD%\socks-proxy-agent\dist\"
npm --global --force install socks-proxy-agent@6.1.1
node --trace-deprecation socks-proxy-agent
```

After this, got some deprecation warnings, but npm starts works.

To view more info about warnings, run this:

```
CD /D "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules"
node --trace-deprecation socks-proxy-agent
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Check if all old files in the nodejs folder after 'uninstall' are deleted!!
This must work!

Answer (score 0):

-> Check npm -v
Anyone of these should work:-

1. Upgrade Node.js
2. Reinstall - Make sure you remove all the cache files
3. Check Node.js file path in environment and system variables